# Why does Flex slider not work with min-max dynamic range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I want to show 3 thumbnails in mobile and 4 in desktop in flex slider. For that I am using [Carousel with dynamic min/max ranges](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/dynamic-carousel-min-max.html) version of flex slider. If you resize that page you'd see number of thmubanils changing as per browser window width. But when I use use the same code in my website or jsfiddle or anywhere it doesn't work. Here is the [jsfiddle proof](http://jsfiddle.net/htu0L4jo/4/) and same code here:

```js
(function() {

  // store the slider in a local variable
  var $window = $(window),
    flexslider = {
      vars: {}
    };

  // tiny helper function to add breakpoints
  function getGridSize() {
    return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 2 :
      (window.innerWidth < 900) ? 3 : 4;
  }


  $window.load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 210,
      itemMargin: 5,
      minItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
      maxItems: getGridSize() // use function to pull in initial value
    });
  });

  // check grid size on resize event
  $window.resize(function() {
    var gridSize = getGridSize();

    flexslider.vars.minItems = gridSize;
    flexslider.vars.maxItems = gridSize;
  });
}());
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
      </li>
      <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I am thinking to report this as an issue on github but I am wary as to why then it works on actual flex slider website.

Answer (score 6):

It's strange that the official doc of this slider missing this crucial information. You have to set instance of slider to `flexslider` global variable when it's started or loaded.

Working example.

```js
 (function() {

        // store the slider in a local variable
        var $window = $(window),
            flexslider = {
                vars: {}
            };

        // tiny helper function to add breakpoints
        function getGridSize() {
            return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 2 :
                (window.innerWidth < 900) ? 3 : 4;
        }

       
        $window.ready(function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: false,
                itemWidth: 210,
                itemMargin: 5,
                minItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
                maxItems: getGridSize(),
             start: function(slider){
                //set slider instance to flexslider variable
               flexslider = slider;
           }
            });
        });

        // check grid size on resize event
        $window.resize(function() {
            var gridSize = getGridSize();
            flexslider.vars.minItems = gridSize;
            flexslider.vars.maxItems = gridSize;
        });
        
    }());
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
 </div>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and its astonishing they didn't mention this in docs. I didn't read the actual source `view-source:http://flexslider.woothemes.com/dynamic-carousel-min-max.html` fully. I should have gone to the bottom to see the actual initialization.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working example for min-max dynamic range.**

```
    var $window = jQuery(window),
    flexslider = {
        vars: {}
    };
    
    function getGridSize() {
            return (window.innerWidth <= 767) ? 2 : (window.innerWidth <= 900) ? 2 : (window.innerWidth <= 1024) ? 3 : (window.innerWidth > 1025) ? 5 : 5;
}

$window.ready(function() {
        jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 248,
            itemMargin: 5,      
            minItems: 2,
            maxItems: getGridSize(),
            controlNav: false
        });
```